# Dynamic datatypes in object list

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

long foo = 1;
List<long> bar = new List<long>(){ 1,2,3 }; 

bool someBool = false;

list.Add(new { someProp = someBool ? foo : bar });
```

Why can't `someProp` datatype act dynamic? The datatype isn't specified as the object key so I don't see the problem.

> There is no implicit conversion between long and `List<long>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)*(also known as ternary operator)* `?`. It is suppose to **return a single type** of object, since  `long` and `List<long>` are different. You are getting the error.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression **must be
>   the same**, **or an implicit conversion must exist** from one type to
>   the other.

A simplest and more readable alternative *(IMO)* would be:

```
if (someProp == someBool)
    list.Add(new { someProp = foo });
else
    list.Add(new { someProp = bar });
```

But the above two would be different `Anonymous type` objects.

Or you can get rid of Anonymous object and simply add the two to list, since it is `List<object>` like:

```
if (someProp == someBool)
    list.Add(foo);
else
    list.Add(bar);
```

Comment: In other words, I can't make an inline conversion I guess

Comment: @Johan, one way would be to cast each to (object), but better if you use a simple `if`, would be more readable IMO

Comment: Ok, your example would make `foo` a list though. But perhaps that's necessary

Comment: @Johan, no `foo` would be `long` and added to `List<object>` as an object.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But then it would result in a long value only, and not with the key "someProp", right?

Comment: @Johan, oh, no I got you, you are trying to create an anonymous object with property `someProp` and then adding it to a list. Having it in `? operator` would fail, since doing something like `list.Add(new { someProp = someBool ? new { someProp = foo } : new { someProp = bar } });` would result in two different anonymous types. Check the edited answer is that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The ? operator requiers to have the same type for your expressions. You can cast your foo and bar to object type manually (explicitly) to the same type, like this:

```
 list.Add(new { someProp = someBool ? (object)foo : bar });
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`?: Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Either the type of `first_expression` and `second_expression` **must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other**.

As the error says, there is no implicit conversion between `long` and `List<long>`. `long` is an integer type and `List<long>` is a generic type.

As an alternative, you can use explicit conversation with both of them to `object` like:

```
(object)foo : (object)bar
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but are you trying to convert `List<long>` (bar) to `Int64` ?

Comment: @Habib Ups, InvalidCastException.. I totaly forgot it. Thanks.